# fastest way to get the total number of non-printable chars in bytes object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for something like this:

```
allBytes = b'\1Hello World!\127\0'
print(countNonPrintables(allBytes))  # prints 3
```

You could iterate over all bytes and determine their printability manually, but that is a bit too slow for me, especially for bytes objects > 2k bytes.

(slow) Example:

```
def countNonPrintables(allBytes: bytes) -> int:
    nonPrintablesCount = 0
    for b in allBytes:
        # DEL:
        if b == b'\127':
            nonPrintablesCount += 1
            continue
        if ord(b) < 32:
            # BS, HT, ESC, FF:
            if b not in {b'\b', b'\t', b'\033', b'\014'}:
                nonPrintablesCount += 1
    return nonPrintablesCount
```

Comment: You should probably consider *all* bytes in a `bytes` object as non-printable; `bytes` is for binary data, `str` is for actual text.

Comment: Use `bytes.translate()` to delete all printable characters from the bytestring, take the `len()` of the result?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are deciding is or isnt printable but you can make use of the python string method `isprintable`

> Return True if the string is printable, False otherwise. A string is
>   printable if all of its characters are considered printable in repr()
>   or if it is empty.

So you can just loop over each char and call the isprintable method

```py
allBytes = b'\1Hello World!\127\0'
non_print_count = len([char for char in allBytes.decode() if not char.isprintable()])
print(non_print_count)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2
```

Comment: No need  to loop over the characters. `allBytes.decode('ascii').isprintable()` works across the entire string.

Comment: @MarkTolonen How do you go from the boolean result to the number, though?

Comment: @MarkTolonen that will only tell you if the string has printable chars but wont tell you how many. the OP specifically wants to know how many of the chars are non printable.

Comment: How much faster than the OP's solution is this?

Comment: running the OP'code results in a type error when calling ord. Wrapping the OP code of ord in a try excpt block and measuring with timeit gives `around 11 seconds for OP code and 2 seconds for my code. However i am not sure if thats a fair comparison since i wrapped the ord code in a try block in the OP code

Comment: decoding the bytes in the op code so the code performs on the string give a run time around 2.2 and my code around 1.6. So not hugely faster. I guess if the OP considers a printable char one that is only in the ascii pritnable range 32 to 126 then this could be made faster specicailly looking for that